# How to make a function which returns the response of an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function which makes an ajax request (see code below), how do I return the response?

Code:

```
const ajaxreq = (url) => {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let res = "";
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = _ => {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        res = this.responseText
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

I have tried placing the return statment inside the `xhttp.onreadystatechange`, but this doesn't make the function `ajaxreq` return that value, only the anonymous function. If I place the return statement after `xhttp.send();`, then the request doesn't have enough time to fulfill and the function just returns an empty string.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The reason why it is not working is that the function completes long before the request is answered, I would look into using an async function.

Comment: It looks like maybe you are trying to call an async method in a synchronous manner.  If you want to call a function and have it return the results of an ajax call, that ajax call will need to by synchronous.

Comment: @Seano666 but synchronous xhr requests are a  terrible practice since they block the whole UI and are deprecated by browser vendors. Not a best practice suggestion

Comment: @charlietfl Agreed, I wasn't trying to address best practices but just trying to reframe his issue so he can understand it better.

Comment: @Seano666 What is a better practice?